# Using ant with AWS CodeBuild - build.xml does not exist and other questions for a newbie

Tags: amazon-web-services, ant, aws-codebuild

I am trying to switch over to using CodeBuild to build my code so I can then easily push it to my EC2 instances instead of manually building and copying.

I can manually run ant on my station and all will build as it should.
I am now trying to use the AWS CodeBuild console to try this.
I zipped up my source code files and put it in an S3 bucket and put its location in the source fields of AWS CodeBuild. I have the build.xml in this same bucket and I also put the build.xml in the base of the codes zip file. In the build commands I put "ant".

I assume that the build.xml needs to go somewhere else?
Do I need more then just "ant" in the build commands? That is all I use when i manually build the project.

From what I have read i should be able to zip up my code , put it in the S3 location and CodeBuild will extract it and build it correct?

Also, under "Environment: How to Build" - what is the "Output files" section for? It's not for the artifacts that are built correct?

Any other tips or tricks? I am very new to all of this so any help is appreciated! I just learned about ant this week. This is building a rather large project with many classes being built - Will this cause an issue? Like I stated earlier - I do have it building file if I run it manually on my system.

Here is the error I get when I build through Code Build:

```
    [Container] 2019/03/21 15:32:27 Entering phase BUILD
    [Container] 2019/03/21 15:32:27 Running command ant
    Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
    Build failed
```

---

I figured out my issue - I zipped the build files from the folder level and not the root level. I re-zipped and it can now see the build.xml.

I built again with these changes and it looks like I am close! It failed for the following -

```
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/03/21 20:57:13 Expanding myapp.jar
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/03/21 20:57:13 Skipping invalid artifact path myapp.jar
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/03/21 20:57:13 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS Success: false
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/03/21 20:57:13 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found
```

Isn't myapp.jar what the build is creating?

I am very confused as to what the Artifact/name should be - isn't this what is being created from the build? It is asking for an ARN - how can there be an ARN for it when it is not created?

Also very confused as to what the Environment/Output files is? It is required but I have no idea what should go in this field? It states that output files can not be empty. Does this mean it wants all the class files that are being built? If so then this build is creating over 30 class files in multiple locations - that is a ton to list.

Thanks
Ernie

Comment: looks like your setup is correct (at least from your description) `build.xml` must be at the root of your ZIP.  An easy way to debug that is to add diagnose commands in your `buildspec.yaml`  For example, if one of your command is `ls -alR /` you will see in the log the full file system of the build environment.  Or just `ls -alR` to see the current directory.  You will see what has been downloaded and unzipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working! I will post my findings for others going that might be struggling -

So I figured out that the "Outputs" means what are all the files and/or directories that you want to go into your final artifact after all is built.

I have two directories that I want in the final jar artifact. One is WebContent and the other is build. They both have multiple sub-directories. I put `"WebContent/*,build/*"` in the output files field. It gave  me a jar artifact but when I open the jar it did not have any sub-directories. In order to get it to include all sub-directories I had to make the output files field with  `"WebContent/**/*,build/**/*"`. All sub-directories are now in the zip and it appears as if the build was successful. 
Hopefully this can help others out.
Now on to creating a script for this and also getting this to work from GitLab.